# Access by pointer to multi-dimensional static arrays in C/C++

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array, dereference

I know, that static arrays are laid out contiguously in memory.
So, for example, `int T[10][10]` is basically stored the same way as `int T[100]`.
I can access element of index i, j many ways, for example:

```
int T[10][10];
/*filling array*/
int i=3, j=7;
int x = T[i][j];
//EDIT - old and wrong: int * ptr = T;
int * ptr = &T[0][0];
int y = *(ptr + 10* i + j);
```

On the other hand, when I create dynamicaly allocated 2-dimensional array by myself:

```
int ** T;
T = malloc(10 * sizeof(int *));
for(i = 0; i < N; i++) 
    T[i] = malloc(10 * sizeof(int));
```

My array contains pointers to

It is obvious, that I can access element of this array by:

```
int i=3, j=7;
int x = *(*(T+i)+j);
```

And now my question: why and how does it work for static arrays?
Why does

```
int T[10][10];
/*filling array*/
int i=3, j=7;
int x = *(*(T+i)+j);
```

return good value to `x`, when this table doesn't contain pointers to arrays? `*(*(T+i))` shouldn't have sense there in my opinion, end even if, it should return `T[0][i]`, as T points at the first element of array. How does compiler interpret this, is `*` something other than dereference here?  Enlighten me.

Comment: 1) C is not C++ is not C. This does not compile as C++. 2) Your prerequisite is wrong: `int **` is **not** a 2D array and cannot point to one nor represent one. 3) Allocate a 2D array. Why do you think what you asumme for a static array is not also true for a dynamically allocated 2D array?

Comment: trying to access a 2D array through pointers is a bad idea. 2D arrays are stored differently on different machines.

Comment: @MarkYisri: Err no!  Writing `T[i][j]` and `*(*(T+i)+j)` are utterly identical (by the definition of the `[]` operator).

Comment: @MartinBonner: Both have very different semantics for 2D arrays and _pointers to pointers_ (aka jagged arrays)! Identical syntax does not imply identical semantics!

Comment: @TheVee: Have you *looked* at the definition of the [] operator?  The abstract machine will involve two dereferences.  The compiler will then optimize it to the expression you show.  (Although note that it will actually be `*((int*)T + i*s + j)` - the cast is necessary because T decays to "pointer to array of 10 integers" - and the offsetting would be all wrong).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For starters:

```
int * ptr = T;
```

That's not going to actually work, at least without your compiler yelling at you. Very loudly. The correct way to do this is:

```
int * ptr = &t[0][0];
```

This point is actually very relevant to your question.

As you know, when used in an expression, an array gets decayed to a pointer. For example:

```
char foo[10];

bar(foo);
```

When used in an expression, like a parameter to a function, the array decays to a pointer to the underlying type. `foo` gets you a `char *`, here.

However, and this is the key point: the array only decays one level. If the array is a two-dimensional array, the array does not get decayed to the underlying value, an `int` in this case. The two dimensional array reference decays to a pointer to a one-dimensional array:

```
int T[10][10];
/*filling array*/
int i=3, j=7;
int x = *(*(T+i)+j);
```

The sequence of steps that occurs here:

1. `T` decays to a pointer to an array of 10 integers, or `int (*)[10]`
2. The addition of `i` advances the pointer by the given value. The pointer is advanced by the size of the element being pointed to. Since the pointer points to `array of 10 integers`, the pointer is advanced accordingly. If `i` was 2, the pointer is advanced by "two arrays of 10 integers", loosely speaking.
3. The `*` operator takes a "pointer to an array of 10 integers" and gives you "an array of 10 integers" as a result. In other words: from `int (*)[10]` to `int [10]`.
4. Since the result is used in an expression, namely the left operand of `+ j`, and the left operand is an array type, the array type decays to a "pointer to int".
5. `j` is added to the result, and dereferenced.

Comment: `int *ptr = T;` should be equal to `int *ptr = &T[0][0];`

Comment: @MarkYisri - you're wrong. Try it yourself: `t.C:4:14: error: cannot convert ‘int (*)[10]’ to ‘int*’ in initialization
  int * ptr = T;`.

Comment: I somewhat miss the answer. OP seems to ask why identical syntax works for both, the 2D array and the `int **`. Which seems to be the major reason beginners (and some not-so-beginners) think the latter is a 2D array, too (they are wrong).

Comment: C only want an **explicit** cast which is perfectly fine here: `int *ptr = (int *) T;` always give the expected result because the first row of multidimensional array starts... at the beginning of the array!

Answer (score 1):

> Why does
>
> ```
> int T[10][10];
> /*filling array*/
> int i=3, j=7;
> int x = *(*(T+i)+j);
> ```
>
> return good value to `x`

The magic is all in `*(*(T+3)+7)` (I have converted to the literal values).

`T` is an array (of size 10) of arrays (of size 10) of int.

When `T` is used in an an expression it decays into a pointer to its first element, so it decays to "pointer to arrays (of size 10) of int".

Adding an integer to that pointer will advance to the fourth element of the array.

So `T+3` is a pointer to an array of 10 ints, and specifically the fourth such array in T.

`*(T+3)` indirects through that pointer to give an l-value of type "array of 10 ints".

Ah-ha!  That is another array being used in an expression - so it decays into a pointer to it's first element!  (It *wouldn't* decay in `sizeof`, so `sizeof(*(T+3))` would be typically 40.)

`(*(T+3) + 7)` just points at the eight element in the array, and ...

`*(*(T+3) + 7)` is an l-value of type int!